# When are two weighted Lebesgue spaces the same?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(\Omega,\mu)$ be a measure space.

The weighted Lebesgue space $L^1(\Omega,w)$, where $w : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a $\mu$-measurable weight function, is defined as the set of all $\mu$-measurable functions $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that
$$
\|f\|_{L^1(\Omega,w)} = \int_\Omega |f(x)| w(x) \, d\mu(x) < \infty.
$$

**Q: what are sufficient and necessary conditions for $L^1(\Omega,w) = L^1(\Omega,1)$ as Banach spaces?**

It seems sufficient that $w(x) \geq w_0 > 0$ for almost all $x \in X$, where $w_0 > 0$ is a positive lower bound. I am wondering whether that is necessary.

Comment: I don’t think that condition is sufficient either. If it were, given $f\in L^1(\Omega,1)$, take $w\equiv f$, which would imply $f\in L^2(\Omega,1)$

Comment: If $\mu$ is Lebesgue mesaure then a N and S condition is $c\leq w \leq C$ a.e. for some $c,C \in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: This is a fairly subtle issue. Here is a sufficient condition: $\mu$ is an atomless and totally finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $w$ is nonnegative and $\int w~\mathrm d\mu>0$. This follows from all separable nontrivial finite atomless measure algebras being isomorphic.